# Calculating probability of making x baskets

Tags: probability

If I were given the shooting percentage of a basketball player, and if his shot attempts in a game is a random variable Z thats a poisson distribution with mean lambda, how can I find the probability that the player makes x shots in a game?

I don't see where I can use the shooting percentage is the regular poisson formula: P(x; μ) = (e^-μ) (μ^x) / x!

Comment: Do you know how many shots he will take? percentage of total number of shots -> mean?

Comment: no, i think this has to be made into a poisson*binomial distribution?

Comment: If you estimate Poisson hit rate $\lambda$ for one game, are you sure conditions in another game would be sufficiently similar that $\lambda$ estimated from the first game is still relevant?